# How to create installer for revit addin?

Tags: revit-api

I just built a plugin for Revit 2019 and want to create an installer without having to put it on the Autodesk store. How should I go about it? At the moment I just copied the addin file in the addins folder to test it. How should I build an installer so that I can provide it to users so that they can just install it and it starts working? Also, Revit keeps on asking permission to load the addin. Is there any way to do it so that Revit does not ask permission to load the addin? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Kural, did you find the appropriate solution for that? I tried using Inno Setup but it can only copy files to a single folder.. I need this DLL file to be copied to multiple Revit folders

Comment: Hi Amir, have you tried inno installer? you can setup which folder the dll and supporting resources (icon images) get copied to.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use Wix Installer Toolset.

[Wix Website](https://wixtoolset.org/)

[Wix Plugin for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WixToolset.WixToolsetVisualStudio2019Extension)

[Very Informative Youtube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Yf-eDsRrnM&t=5677s)

[Book](https://docplayer.net/40732692-Wix-3-6-a-developer-s-guide-to-windows-installer-xml.html)

It will require some learning how to do it efficiently, but once you learn how to use Wix you will be able to quickly create Installation packages.

Answer (score 0):

My company still use InnoSetup for instalers, it is not that hard but if you what make something more flexible you will need to learn pascal a little.
For the part of permission you need a certifacte that is recognized by Autodesk, no way around this.